# Keycloak-angular x-frame issue

Tags: keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway, keycloak-angular

I have the following issue after setting up Angular-keycloak:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:4200/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

My Angular (app.module.ts) configuration is the following:

```
        keycloak.init({
          config: {
            // url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
            url: window.location.origin + '/auth',
            realm: 'myRealm',
            clientId: 'my-client',
          },
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            // onLoad: 'check-sso',
            // checkLoginIframe: false
            // silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
            //   window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
          },
          loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
          bearerExcludedUrls: ['']
        }))
```

The keycloak server is running on port 8080.

If I access Keycloak directly

> url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth'

everything works fine, I can see the Keycloak login prompt and get a token.

If I use

> url: window.location.origin + '/auth',

and use a proxy server (spring cloud gateway or proxy.conf.json in dev) to redirect to Keycloak, I get this X-Frame error.

I can see the request in the proxy and the following call is successful:

> Request URL:
> http://localhost:4200/auth/realms/IzoaKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html
> Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK

however the response header contains:

```
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

Is this a setup in Keycloak that I am missing?

06/12/2023 update

So it looks like the issue is with the Spring-cloud-gateway that adds the X-Frame-Options:DENY per default.

I tried to disable it by adding the following to my application.yml

```
routes:
 - id: keycloak
              uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth
              predicates:
              - Path=/auth/**
              filters:
              - RemoveResponseHeader=X-Frame-Options
```

but the X-Frame-Options:DENY is still there.

Comment: So it looks like the issue is with the Spring-cloud-gateway that adds the X-Frame-Options:DENY per default. 

I tried to disable it by adding the following to my application.yml

``` routes:
 - id: keycloak
              uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth
              predicates:
              - Path=/auth/**
              filters:
              - RemoveResponseHeader=X-Frame-Options
```

 but the X-Frame-Options:DENY is still there.